# Sequelize migration order of execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I understand how Sequelize migrations and seeder work, but I have not found anywhere that states if they execute in some particular order. So if I start with a database, make a bunch of migrations, and then decide to initialize a brand new database from the original start point, will it execute the migrations in the exact same order.

I am using sequelize-cli to create migrations, so the file name does begin with a timestamp.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For anyone that sees this in the future, it executes in the default sort order of the folder. So when you use the CLI to create a migration and it appends the timestamp, it guarantees that it will execute in the order they were created

Hope this helps

Comment: I am not sure this is always true though. For example, in OSX, 100migration.js will appear before 10migrations.js. The same argument is true for timestamps.

Comment: Timestamps always have the same number of characters unlike 10 vs 100. Sort order goes character by character until it reaches a character that isn't the same

Comment: See you on 21st November, 2286 :)