# Sequelize-cli: Pre-run another seed file before seeding a file?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have created a seeder file using `sequelize-cli` to `bulkInsert` data into a mysql db and it works all fine. However, one of the fields(`userId`) that i'm inserting is a value present in another table(`User`).

**What I was planning to do** is - Run a seed which inserts data into `User` table *first* and then run my second seeder file.

**My doubt** - I can create the seeder files separately but how do I run those in sequence .ie. make sure the "user" seeder file runs and completes before I start seeding the second via `sequelize-cli` ?

Comment: check this post out about the order of migration execution order since it also applies to seeders [Sequelize migration order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429383/sequelize-migration-order-of-execution) (possible duplicate)

Comment: You may also achieve the desired order of execution by manually renaming your seeder files to be in the order you want, for example you can append a numbered prefix like so `1-users-table-seeder.js` `2-other-table-seeder.js`

Comment: Thanks ... this is great help! Also this would mean, we have to group the files now in a folder rather than choosing which one to pre-run. ie. What if I wanted to pre-run a seeder file from another folder(lets say its needed for the other seeder file as well) ?

Comment: You are welcome ... Typically you have a `.sequelizerc` in which you define paths for your (config, migrations, models and seeders) in order to generate a `config.json` (or .js) file by running `sequelize init`, then when you run a sequelize command (for example: `sequelize db:seed:all`) Sequelize will automatically look inside the appropriate paths based on your config.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for the answer.

As far as I have seen, itseems there are 2 options for this as of now:

1. Create a separate seeder files and manually name them in sequence ie. `1-user-seeder.js` and `2-application-seeder.js`. As @Mohdule mentioned in the comments above. **OR**.
2. Import the Sequelize model and create the user within your primary seeder file. Based on [this comment](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/689#issuecomment-451884808).